# How to add click listener in listview footer view button

Tags: android, android-listview

I have created activity with a listview, and adding footer view grammatically. Footer view consists two button(back & next). The issue is when i click on button it doesn't fires click event but when i focus to View(footerview) it trigger click event.

here is my code,

```html
listView.addFooterView(footer_controls,null,true);

                      Button NextButton =(Button) footer_controls.findViewById(R.id.btnNext);
                        NextButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                Toast.makeText(context, "forward clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                LoadData();
                            }
                        });
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did either of the answers below help you? If so please mark which one, thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Write your OnclickListener before adding the footer view
And make sure to set focusable="false" inside xml to your root layout

Answer (score 0):

In the xml layout used for inflating footer_controls, try putting `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"` on the highest root view

For example

```
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

        <Button ...>

        <!--Other Views -->

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code it worked for me... there is no need of holder to call your button you can directly findviewbyid as follow

```
 listSearchResult = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listSearchResult);
    footerView1 = View.inflate(this, R.layout.no_listing_found, null);
    listSearchResult.addFooterView(footerView1,null,false);

    Button NextButton =(Button) findViewById(R.id.btnNext);
    NextButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
           Toast.makeText(context, "forward clicked",           Toats.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            LoadData();
                        }
                    });
```